# Publish an image using Chatter API

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed-tracking, chatter-file

I've been coding an application to connect with Chatter and everything is going ok but I was wondering how to link an image url into my wall, I mean I've read several documents about how to attach a file (picture as well) in the request but I wouldn't like to upload the binary file, I'd like to post a url_image in order to be shown in my wall as a feed.

I've tried to do it but the result wasn't good, it was a link to my image.

DO you know if there is a way to link an image rather than upload it?

Thanks in advance

Diego

Comment: See [this other (answered) question][1]


  [1]: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/image-upload-to-chatter-post